# Sorting blobs in google cloud storage with respect to the last modified date field using python api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a scenario where i want to list blobs and then sort it using the last modified time.

I am trying to do it in python api.

I want to execute this script n number of times, and in each execution i want to list 10 files and perform some operation (e.g copy). I want to save the date of the last file in a config file and want to list the files in another iteration after the last saved date.
Need some suggestion as google api doesn't let us sort the files after listing.

```
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name,prefix=prefix,max_results=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions I can think of.

1. Get pubsub notification every time a file created.Read 10 messages each time or save the topic data to bigquery.
2. After using a file move it to another folder with a metadata file, or update the processed files metadata.
3. Use storage to trigger a function and save the event data to database.
4. If you control the files names and path save them in a easy to query path by using the prefix parameter.

I think the database solution in the must flexible one which give you the best control over the data and the ability to create a dashboard for your data.

Knowing more about your flow will help in order to give you a more fine grained solution.